# Dynamics CRM 365 - Export Activities with parsed Description field

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have task to export Activities including 'Descriptions' filed which contains HTML of the stored email treads. I have to export this field/column as parsed text (not HTML codes, only a real content of the mails).

Actually, when Activities listing is displayed in web, Descriptions column displays exactly what I need, but when I export it to excel, this columns displays HTML codes (and is limited to 1044 chars, so there is no any real body content).

Please, give some advice or link where I can learn how to export this field as it looks in web.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, plain text email body is not stored automatically by OOB CRM. All you have is Rich text stored description field.

There are [multiple different solutions](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/135997/converting-html-e-mail-to-plain-text) to strip the HTML tags & store the plain text in a different field viz code solution, no-code configuration solution using third party like North52, etc.

If you have developers in your team, then C# Plugin would be the best bet to strip & store on creation of Email record itself.

Answer (score 0):

Would a Report Wizard report work to give you the results you need?

Also, Arun's answer was marked as correct (as it should be...)  My only advice would be to store the email body without the HTML tags in a different field.  I've found that stripped HTML tags can do funny things to formatting.

Comment: Thank you, ChrisPerrin, for advice. I'm not experienced in working/development with Dynamics CRM. What I tried is simple export from the view (including 'description' column), and got HTML (even incomplete content, limited to 2000 chars). Also, I installed Power BI and connected it to CRM's raw tables. Here 'description' fields display HTML content, but if I select some of these fields (click on it) preview displays what I need (pure email content). I also uploaded funtion/js file that strips HTML tags to web resources, but how to use this function? It consumes field value as an argument.

Comment: Are you able to run a plugin?  If so, the C# for that would be fairly simple, but not every environment allows it.  My fear with the JavaScript is that you would need to load every file and save it to make the scrip actually run and I don't think you want that.